# Qml: how to disable scrolling/swipe on ListView?

Tags: qt, qml

I implemented a master-detail in QML by using a horizontal list with snap, each list item being a view.

Now I want to disable scrolling/swiping, how do I achieve that? There seems to be no useful `ListView` property for that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`ListView` inherits from the `Flickable` which has `interactive` property. 
Just set

```
interactive: false
```